# Ubuntu Autoinstall - UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi, preseed, autoinstall

We want to use the new ubuntu autoinstall method [Autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-schema). There are some problems getting UEFI boot to work. I've installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 with the normal installer and EFI method and then acquired the following user-data file.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  identity: {hostname: zsrv, password: $6$AYtLXyyVZAea2aLJ$UQxW1cz2vWWNn.17.3QYH5TxZqIMGoLJCpqbBTfClhUKxqouYn7/Yc5Jsq.bCeK0VDLPxbL6xzfJ0xqTb6MLk.,
    realname: root, username: root}
  keyboard: {layout: us, toggle: null, variant: ''}
  locale: C
  network:
    ethernets:
      enp1s0: {dhcp4: true}
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  storage:
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false,
      type: disk, id: disk-vda}
    - {ptable: gpt, wipe: superblock-recursive, preserve: false, name: '',
      grub_device: false, type: disk, id: disk-vdb}
    - {device: disk-vda, size: 536870912, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 1,
      preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-0}
    - {fstype: fat32, volume: partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-vda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 2,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-1}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-1}
    - {device: disk-vdb, size: 24696061952, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 1,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-4}
    - {device: disk-vda, size: 24696061952, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-5}
    - name: md0
      raidlevel: raid1
      devices: [partition-4, partition-5]
      spare_devices: []
      preserve: false
      type: raid
      id: raid-0
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: raid-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-4}
    - {device: format-4, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-4}
    - {device: format-1, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot/efi, type: mount, id: mount-0}
  version: 1
```

The system install runs, but then on next boot I get dumped into the UEFI shell. are there some postinstall commands I need to run to get EFI working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *might* be running into the issue where *curtin* reorders the UEFI boot order during the installation.  It makes the current boot method the first in the boot order.  There is an option to disable this.

Including this snippet in the `storage` section of the `user-data` file will disable the UEFI reorder.

```
  storage:
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: False
```

I've run into this booting from PXE.  After install, I end up booting from PXE again instead of booting from the hard drive.  I'm  not sure why you would end up in the UEFI shell.