# ubuntu 22.04 PXE boot , after installation , physical machines just won't bootfrom harddisk

Tags: pxe

it's really odd. after couples of playing around with ubuntu 22.04 .I have made two ISOs that can be install ubuntu 22.04 server/desktop automatically.

now I'm trying to configure my old PXE server to install ubuntu 22.04 automatically.
I first try netboot.xyz which provide sanboot command to boot from ISO file.
well , it works in virtual machine ( proxmox ) , but not physical machines ( an acer desktop , a lenovo T470 laptop)
I soon decided to give up ipxe , I need more time to study the ipxe.

so I go back to my old but stable PXE server , which already provide ubuntu 18.04,20.04 desktop/server with/without preseed file.

it's not that hard to make ubuntu 22.04 boot with PXE and auto install , here is my configurations.

pxelinux.cfg/default

```
label Ubuntu 22.04 Server auto install
menu label Ubuntu 22.04 Server auto install
kernel tftp://192.168.11.7/images/ubuntu/22.04/amd64/vmlinuz
initrd tftp://192.168.11.7/images/ubuntu/22.04/amd64/initrd.gz
append ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://192.168.11.7/jammy-server/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.11.7/jammy-server/

label Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop auto install
menu label Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop auto install
kernel tftp://192.168.11.7/images/ubuntu/22.04/amd64/vmlinuz
initrd tftp://192.168.11.7/images/ubuntu/22.04/amd64/initrd.gz
append ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://192.168.11.7/jammy-server/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.11.7/jammy-desktop/
```

they are almost the same , besides the last part ( where the user-data/meta-data stores )
so , with this configuration , I create a new VM in proxmox , boot from PXE and select to install desktop without any problems.

the install process takes about 12-15 mins , after the first reboot , I can see the ubuntu login screen.

After the success on the VM, I continued testing with the physical machine
well, the install process also runs without any problem , but after rebooting , these physical machines just won't get into ubuntu, but no error messages , no matter server/desktop I choose. but I'm pretty sure the installtion "completed" , so I boot the machine with Live USB , then pack /var/log/installer , and try to check what's the matter
here is the installer log files.

https://cdn-145.bayfiles.com/r0u1mdrbya/0a9c191e-1655797475/installer.tgz

I have no idea why the same configuration works in VM but hangs in desktop/laptop .I really have no any clues.

Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

update 2022/06/23
I think it's something related to bios/EFI booting issue
I didn't configure storage layout in user-data , just use the support layouts in documents

```
storage:
  layout:
    name: direct
```

according to the URL
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

```
The two supported layouts at the time of writing are “lvm” and “direct”.
By default these will install to the largest disk in a system
```

but it didn't create any ESP partitions.
this is the disk layout in VM after PXE auto install
[image]

I could add custom storage layout to add ESP partition , but in 22.04 , it's really  a disaster to do so.
I have to write many configurations for different type of hard drive.
(/dev/nvme0n1 , /dev/sda , /dev/vda ) or otherwise the install process will fail.

Comment: Does the physical machine do a PXE boot after install?  You may be running into an issue where PXE is made the first boot option and need to use `reorder_uefi` in your autoinstall configuration.  I have noticed that Proxmox VMs using UEFI alway reset their boot order and are not affected by this.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1285074/376778

Comment: even I manually select boot device  , the physical machine just won't boot into ubuntu .
but I use another machine ( ASUS Desktop Server ASUS  TS-110 ) the whole process runs like a gem without any problems !!
that really confuse me , why the same configuration and process cause so many different situuations ?